# running docker compose on swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a compose file:

docker-compose.yml

```
openjdk-6b36-jdk:
  image: java:openjdk-6b36-jdk
  volumes:
   - ./src:/src
   - ./build/openjdk-6b36-jdk:/build
  command: /src/compileAndTest

openjdk-7u79-jdk:
  image: java:openjdk-7u79-jdk
  volumes:
   - ./src:/src
   - ./build/openjdk-7u79-jdk:/build
  command: /src/compileAndTest

openjdk-8u66-jdk:
  image: java:openjdk-8u66-jdk
  volumes:
   - ./src:/src
   - ./build/openjdk-8u66-jdk:/build
  command: /src/compileAndTest
```

it runs fine:

```
-bash-4.2$ docker-compose up
Starting compose_openjdk-7u79-jdk_1
Starting compose_openjdk-8u66-jdk_1
Starting compose_openjdk-6b36-jdk_1
Attaching to compose_openjdk-8u66-jdk_1, compose_openjdk-7u79-jdk_1, compose_openjdk-6b36-jdk_1
openjdk-7u79-jdk_1  | Hello, World
openjdk-8u66-jdk_1  | Hello, World
openjdk-6b36-jdk_1  | Hello, World
compose_openjdk-7u79-jdk_1 exited with code 0
compose_openjdk-8u66-jdk_1 exited with code 0
compose_openjdk-6b36-jdk_1 exited with code 0
```

i would like to run this across swarm cluster
What would be the command to do so?

would it be something like `docker -H :4000 run <something>?`
because that the command i used to run images on swarm nodes

I can run `docker -H :4000 run hello-world` fine but those are docker images. how do you run docker compose across swarm cluster?

i.e. i want compose_openjdk-7u79-jdk_1 to go to one node and compose_openjdk-8u66-jdk_1 to go to another node and so forth?

Comment: remove volume mounting here and run it will work. If you want to use volumes in swarm mode. you need to make app to run in swarm manager with named volumes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can add `contraints` to services:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/#/manual-scheduling

I have not tested it myself.

Comment: yes but that documentaiton says "docker-compose up" to get it to swarm. it doesnt seme to work for me.

Comment: You may need to use `version: '2'` of the `docker-compose.yml` file. Would you update your post with the entire `docker-compose.yml` file?